# When I hold Right a Click AND Left Click, it goes back a page

Tags: mouse, right-click, webpage

When I click left click and right click at the same time, it goes back a page. It also happens when I spam right click sometimes. It doesn’t matter if the cursor is on the top half or the bottom half of the screen. It doesn’t matter what mouse I use. It’s annoying when I can’t play online shooters.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [Rocker gestures](https://help.vivaldi.com/article/mouse-gestures/#rocker) in Vivaldi

> Rocker Gestures let you quickly go back and forward in history.
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Mouse > Rocker Gestures.
> 2. Tick the box for Allow Rocker Gestures to enable this feature.
> 3. **To go back in history, click the right mouse button, quickly followed by the left mouse button.**
> 4. To do forward in history, click the left mouse button, quickly followed by the right mouse button.

Answer (score -1):

Nvm, I just found the answer, it only happens when using Vivaldi. If you switch browsers, the issue in question disappears. Weird.